# Operator precedence - increment versus member access

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

Consider this:

```
++iterator->some_value
```

Will the iterator be forwarded before `some_value` is accessed?

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) *increment* and *member access* both have the same precedence of 2. Does the order in which they are listed matter? Or is this undefined - compiler specific?

Comment: @zainuldin By following the guidelines given/set by SO.

Comment: @zainuldin did you [read this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/) yet, particularly the section titled "How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?"?

Comment: @zainuldin The link tells you everything you need to know. Nobody is going to upvote your questions out of pity.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat if can't do this it's okay!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that preincrement and postincrement have different precedences, so the code snippet you've posted doesn't quite match the explanatory text you've linked.

The preincrement operator has a lower precedence than the member access operator, so `++iterator->some_value` is the equivalent of `++(iterator->some_value)`.

If instead you had `iterator->some_value++` where they both had the same precedence, then the left-to-right associativity comes into effect, and it would be processed as `(iterator->some_value)++`.

Answer (score 1):

The **member access** operator `->` has higher precedence over the prefix increment operator. Thus the expression `++iterator->some_value` is grouped as  if you had written

```
++(iterator->some_value)
```

---

On the other hand, **if** your were to write the expression `iterator->some_value++` then since both the member access operator `->` and the postfix increment operator have the same precedence, so left-to-right associativity will be used, which will make this expression equivalent to writing :

```
(iterator->some_value)++
```